# Two Foreach Loops

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My objective is to combine two foreach loops. Here is the code:

```
<?php
        if(isset($query))
        {
            foreach($query as $row){//there should be another foreach loop here with the condition ($query2->row) 
                echo '<a href="'.base_url().'site/timeline/'.$row->projectId.'"><div class="projbox"> ';
                echo '<div id="proj-head">'.$row->Title.'</a></div>';
                date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
                $now = date('Y-m-d');
                /*if (($now>$row2->pre_proc_conference)&&($now<$row2->post_of_ieab)){
                    echo '<progress value="11" max="100" id="prog-head"></progress><br/>';
                }
                if (($now>$row2->post_of_ieab)&&($now<$row2->pre_bid_conference)){
                    echo '<progress value="22" max="100" id="prog-head"></progress><br/>';
                }
                if (($now>$row2->pre_bid_conference)&&($now<$row2->elegibility_check)){
                    echo '<progress value="33" max="100" id="prog-head"></progress><br/>';
                }
                if (($now>$row2->elegibility_check)&&($now<$row2->sub_bid)){
                    echo '<progress value="44" max="100" id="prog-head"></progress><br/>';
                }
                if (($now>$row2->sub_bid)&&($now<$row2->bid_evaluation)){
                    echo '<progress value="55" max="100" id="prog-head"></progress><br/>';
                }
                if (($now>$row2->bid_evaluation)&&($now<$row2->post_qualification)){
                    echo '<progress value="66" max="100" id="prog-head"></progress><br/>';
                }
                if (($now>$row2->post_qualification)&&($now<$row2->notice_of_award)){
                    echo '<progress value="77" max="100" id="prog-head"></progress><br/>';
                }
                if (($now>$row2->notice_of_award)&&($now<$row2->contract_signing)){
                    echo '<progress value="88" max="100" id="prog-head"></progress><br/>';
                }
                if ($now>$row2->contract_signing){
                    echo '<progress value="100" max="100" id="prog-head"></progress><br/>';
                }*/
                echo 'Date Started: '.$row->datestarted.'
                      <br />Mode of Procurement: '.$row->procurementmode.'<br/>';
                echo '</div></a>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

How can I do this? There is 2 queries I passed from the controller $query and $query2. The values from $query2 will be the one to generate the value of the progress bars. The values from $query will be the one to generate the other details.

Comment: I don't understand... just imbricate both your loops, what is exactly the issue ?

Comment: Can you add more detail on this.

Comment: i dont see the second loop

Comment: The second loop is supposedly performing the same time as the foreach($query as $row) (it's in the comment @RandykaYudhistira)

Comment: What imbricate Sir @Bartdude?

Comment: The ones on the comments are the ones that should be happening.

Comment: When you write $query2->row, is "row" the same as $row produce by the loop ?

Comment: I was suggesting that you just put the second loop inside the first one

Comment: Then I will have the wrong result Sir @Bartdude. If I put the other loop inside, I will have 3 progress bars inside a div. I want one progress bar per div.

Comment: Can you show us a var_dump of $query and $query2 and an example of what's your expected output ?